# Powershell PS-ReadlineOption reset after restarting Powershell

Tags: powershell, colors

I tried changing my Powershell colors with the PS-ReadLineOption -colors command, which works fine except that when I close Powershell and restart it everything is set to default again.

Is there a way to keep those changes?

Comment: Reading on here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/PSReadline/Set-PSReadlineOption?view=powershell-5.0 is it not just a case of throwing in a -HistorySaveStyle flag?

Comment: Hmm didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself. It seems that you can't save the color settings but instead you can create a powershell profile script and set the colors there. The script is executed when you open up a new powershell.

here's an article about those profiles: https://www.gsx.com/blog/bid/81096/enhance-your-powershell-experience-by-automatically-loading-scripts